# How do I get a refund of an iTunes gift card with illegible numbers for redeeming the value?

Tags: itunes, ios-appstore

When scratching the back of an iTunes gift card to get the numbers to redeem it, the numbers scratched off and now I can't redeem the value of it.  How can I get a refund or a new gift card with the same value?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was in this situation once. I went to the Apple support site, followed what they said then filled out the email form. They ask you for what you can make out of the code, and then the serial number of the gift card.
This is the link to the [gift card contact page](https://getsupport.apple.com/?caller=kbase&PGF=PGF63003&category_id=SC0082&symptom_id=20256).

Where it says 'specific request' select 'my code is scratched or unreadable.' Proceed to fill in the form as best you can and send it off. I got a response in less that 48 hours, and the answer they gave me allowed me to redeem my card.

Information for identifying the different information on your card can be found [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201195).

In answer to your original question, I don't actually know, but I hope this assistance means you will no longer have a need to refund the card. Hope this helps.